# APK Expansion file download doesn´t work

Tags: android, android-lvl, apk-expansion-files

I need to integrate expansion support into my app. What I got so far is I have the example DownloaderActivity, Service and Receiver in my app now.

Now I setup the XAPKFile

```
        return new XAPKFile[]{new XAPKFile(
            true,//is main?
            3,//Version
            4550105L)};//File size
```

The File size is correct, it´s not the "size on disk", but I also tried that one.

The version number is always equal to my package version of the apk.

I uploaded both as an alhpa version into the market to test it and make it not accessible to others yet.

The testing account is the developer account.

The Problem is now, the download won´t start. I´m always getting the hint "Download failed because you may not have purchased this app".

I´ve debugged the app within the downloader service a lot yesterday, to find the actual problem. The responsecode I got back from Server in the LicenseValidator.java verify method is always NOT_LICENSED.

The RSA Key is the right one.

Why is my app not licensed?

Edit:

I´ve tested it now on another account, getting a different error:

[image]

The Account has been added to the developer console´s licensing as a test account

Answer (score 1):

I´ve waited one day and now it magically works. Seems that Google needed some time for progressing.

Edit:

Now it stopped working again with the error "Download failed because the resources could not be found", how funny...

Comment: did you sort this out? :D I want to kill someone right now!

Comment: :D actually, I don´t know what I´ve done, but it started working again. Sadly I´m not anymore into this project

Comment: Well, the only way is wait a bit after testing I guess... I used the licence testing and tried all the responses.. and it looks like the server got stuck on "connection error"

Answer (score 0):

When I use Android 5.0.1 I set targetSdkVersion 19 after then my problem solved.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

[image]

Wehn I use Android 5.0.1 I set targetSdkVersion 21 I have below error.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

**download failed because you may not have purchased this app**

LogCat error like this:

```
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153): Process: your_app_package_name, PID: 14153
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1674)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1773)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker.checkAccess(LicenseChecker.java:150)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloaderService$LVLRunnable.run(DownloaderService.java:768)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-28 15:06:34.521: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file size same as expansion file uploaded to the android console,

```
 return new XAPKFile[]{new XAPKFile(
        true,//is main?
        3,//Version
        99695373L)};//File size
```

[image]

And I had the same problem also, but the problem come from here

```
boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
    for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
        String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);
        if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It returning `false`, so the app can not validated the expansion file even the file is downloaded, so I fixed by adding `else`

```
boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
    for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
        String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);

        if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, true)) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and on account setting, setting licensed test response to LICENSED[image]

Hope that can help you :)